# Do the sample sizes for the Kruskal-wallis test need to be similar?

Tags: statistical-significance, sample-size, statistical-power, kruskal-wallis-test

I have a dataset with around 42000 samples. For each sample I have a continuous variable "abs_error" (coming from a experiment ran before, not relevant here) and the subject's race and sex. I want to test if the error is significantly different for subjects of different races and sex, i.e. compare white males, white females, asian males, etc, to a total of 6 subgroups.
Several things to take into account:

1. The counts for each subgroup are 41417 white subjects and then 576 asian and 286 black, so the sample sizes for each subgroup are very different.
2. I have tested the normality of each subgroup sample with the Shapiro-Wilk test and all samples are not normal.

Upon this, I have concluded that I should use the Kruskal-Wallis (instead of ANOVA, given the non-normality of the samples, although the 'homogeneity of variances' condition is verified).
My questions are:
1 - Can I just run the test with the full sample of each sub-group, or should I take a sample of equal size for each sub-group, even if that means only having  a sample of size 100 for each (given that the number of black patients is so low)?
2- Given that the Kruskal-Wallis is the equivalent of a **one-way** ANOVA, and here we have two factors (race and sex), is it a valid solution to - upon a result from the Kruskal-Wallis test where we reject the null hypothesis - run two post-hoc Conover tests, one to check for differences between the race groups and one between the sex groups?
I did this as I didn't find an non-parametric alternative to a two-way ANOVA that seemed appropriate for this situation.